Ubuntu 24.10 (upgrade): Must login to Ubuntu desktop before logging in to sway: Account issues
I have upgraded to Ubuntu 24.10 from Ubuntu 24.04.
After upgrading I had to login to Ubuntu desktop, open Settings -> online accounts
and re-authenticate my Google and Microsoft accounts.
But I still have problems when logging in to Sway window-manager directly after boot: My browser (Vivaldi) fails to authenticate with Vivaldi server, and thus can not open.
If I instead login to the Ubuntu desktop, I can open Vivaldi there. I can then logout of Ubuntu desktop, and then use Sway window manager with the expected functionality.
So it seems to me that some background service is started by Ubuntu desktop, that is not started by logging in to Sway.
